# How to handle escape characters in pyspark. Trying to replace escape character with NULL

Tags: pyspark, replace, unicode-escapes

I'm trying to replace a escape character with NULL in pyspark dataframe. Data in dataframe looks like below

```
Col1|Col2|Col3 
1|\026\026|026|abcd026efg.
```

Col2 is a garbage data and trying to replace with NULL. Tried replace and regex_replace functions to replace '\026' with Null value, because of escape character (" \ "), data is not replaced with NULL value.

```
 replace(col2, "026",  'abcd') 
 replace(Col2, "\026",  'abcd')
```

Finally,

I want my data as

```
Col1|Col2|Col3 
1|NULL|026|abcd026efg.
```

Highly appreciate for thoughts to resolve this scenario.

Thanks
-EVR

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Urz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace  all digits and preceding non digits

```
 import pyspark.sql.functions as F
 df.withColumn('col2',F.regexp_replace('col2','\D\d+',None)).show()

+----+----+-----------+
|col1|col2|       col3|
+----+----+-----------+
|   1|null|abcd026efg.|
+----+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. got an error "name 'F' is not defined". do we need to import any library, can you please give me the snippet of the code

Comment: Hahh.. IT WORKED !!!!!!!     Thanks for you help.... Can you brief me what's happening with '\026' and explain what does '\D\d+' means

Comment: I am using pythons regular expressions n. This is how it works 
\D for non digits
\d for digits
+ Greedily match everything on the left

Comment: My data is little more complex than earlier, 

'\026' is randomly spreadout through all the columns and I have replace to '\026'  with NULL across all columns

below is my sample input data

col1|col2|col3 
1|\026\026|abcd026efg 
2|\026\026|\026\026\026 
3|ad026eg|\026\026 
4|ad026eg|xyad026  

and, my out data should be 

col1|col2|col3 
1|NULL|abcd026efg 
2|NULL|NULL 
3|ad026eg|NULL 
4|ad026eg|xyad026