# Replace all strings with escape characters across all columns with NULLs in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have a spark dataframe with approximately 100 columns.  NULL instances are currently recorded as \N.  I want to replace all instances of \N with NULL however, because the backslash is an escape character, I'm having difficulty.  I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375876/how-to-handle-escape-characters-in-pyspark-trying-to-replace-escape-character-w) article that uses regex for a single column, however, I need to iterate over all columns

I've even tried the solution in the article on a single column, however, I still cannot get it to work.  Ordinarily, I'd use R and am to solve this issue in R using the following code:

```
df <- sapply(df,function(x) {x <- gsub("\\\\N",NA,x)})
```

However, given I'm new to Pyspark I'm having quite a lot of difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

data = [ ('0','\\N','\\N','3')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['col1','col2','col3','col4'])

print('before:')
df.show()

for col in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(col, psf.when(psf.col(col)==psf.lit('\\N'), psf.lit(None)).otherwise(psf.col(col)))

print('after:')
df.show()

before:
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   0|  \N|  \N|   3|
+----+----+----+----+

after:
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   0|null|null|   3|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, although I had to ensure I included: import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

Comment: Good to hear, edited to include the imports

Comment: Really good stuff!  Thanks again :-)